# Has accuracy metrics calculation changed from TensorFlow 1.14 to TensorFlow 2.3?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, metrics

The exact same code & input data give me different accuracy results in training with TensorFlow 1.14 and TensorFlow 2.3. In 1.14, accuracy is >0.99 right from the start whereas in 2.3, it is around 0.75. The loss values are approximately the same in both cases, around 0.01-0.03. Is it just the metrics calculation that changed or should I suspect something more serious is going on with my code?

Here are the relevant parts of the code. It is a multilabel, multiclass CNN.

```
    ... # (other layers)
    model.add(layers.Dense(38, activation='sigmoid'))   # Output layer
    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    history = model.fit(x=x_train, y=y_train, validation_data=(x_valid,y_valid), epochs=5, verbose=2, shuffle=True)
```

Comment: [`tf.keras.layers.Dense`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dense) and others have `initializer` parameters that can be set to fixed values. By default many layers (including `Dense`) have various random initializers. Fixing the initializers to be deterministic might help make clearer comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

For tensorflow >=2.2.0, looks like binary_accuracy must be stated instead of just accuracy in metrics param for multi-label prediction.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/41114